# Elegantly handle global variables how?

Tags: python

```
def doSomething(index):
    if index == 0:
        while flag1:
            do stuff
    elif index == 1:
        while flag2:
            do stuff

    ...
```

In a multi-threaded environment, `flag1` and `flag2` are booleans(global variables) which would be modified somewhere else. It would be really elegant if I could do it like this:

```
def doSomething(index):
    while (put either flag1 or flag2 here according to index):
        do stuff
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

**1.** Saw a few people suggesting list, the thing is, list like this `flags = [flag1, flag2, flag3, ...]` assume`flag1 = True`, `flag2 = False`, `flag3 = True`, this makes `flags = [True, False, True]`, and if you modify `flag1 = False` somewhere else in another thread, `flags` won't change accordingly, so this definitely won't work.

[image]

**2.** Actually I found one original answers suggesting `while [flag1, flag2, flag3, ...][index]`, and it actually works! Just don't know why he deleted his answer?

**Interesting Part:**

Just tested the following part:

```
def doSomething(index):
    flags = [flag1, flag2, flag3]
    while flags[index]:
        do stuff
```

And it WON'T work, but interestingly enough, this actually works:

```
def doSomething(index):
    while [flag1, flag2, flag3][index]:
        do stuff
```

So I suppose `[flag1, flag2, flag3][index]` actually return the original variable? Anybody can explain a bit more?

Comment: The question isn't really about global variables; the same sort of flow could be required with local variables just as well. Could you come up with a better question title please?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what happen is when you create list or dictionary of reference, reference of a literal does not change.

When you create list of flags, `flags[0]` points to what `flag1` points to, which is `False`.

When you reassign values to `flag1`, you are changing to what the `flag1` is pointing, but `flags[0]` is still pointing to `False`.

One way you can work around this is to add one more layer of object wrapper. If your boolean values are contained in an object, since the reference in the list points to what labels point to, which is the object, change in fields will be reflected.

In fact, why not just use `flags` as a global variable? If the script is smart enough to hardcode changes in one specific flag at a particular place, perhaps we can replace

```
flag1 = False
```

with

```
flags[0] = False
```

or even with a message-passing

```
flags[mess] = False
```

`flags` can be list, dict, or normal objects. The good old message-passing style all over the place!

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more elegant *design* solution to this problem, but to get around variables not being updated in a list, simply wrap them in a `class`

```
>>> class Flag():
    def __init__(self,flag):
        self.flag = flag


>>> flag_1 = Flag(True)
>>> flag_2 = Flag(False)
>>> flag_list = [flag_1, flag_2]
>>> flag_1.flag = False
>>> flag_list[0].flag
False
```

Comment: I think Shane wants to avoid creating a needless Wrapper class, as he probably already has code configured to use a different class.

Comment: @ThomasHobohm Which is why I highlighted that this seems to be more of a design issue, and looks like it is lending itself towards refactoring to achieve the desired effects (see the high coupling already between global flags -- what if they change class or type etc?)

Comment: You do realize that the code in his post is just an example, right?

Comment: @ThomasHobohm you mean `do stuff` isn't valid python syntax? :)

Comment: I mean, he probably has way more complex code, in which refactoring would take way longer. He's also using multithreading, so he probably can't pass these variables around to all the different threads easily without making them Global.

Comment: @ThomasHobohm I realize this is a snippet, but hardcoding in global flags will cause issues down the road; there is high coupling and no information hiding. Either way, this is getting off topic as this isn't code review.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `ternary` operator.

```
def doSomething(index):
    while (flag1 if index else flag2):
        do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can have several `index` values, then have a list of flags:

```
flags = [flag0, flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4]
```

then you can use the index to query the appropriate flag:

```
def doSomthing(index):
    while(flags[index]):
        do_stuff()
```

**Edit**:

For this to work, the global variables are *not* `flag0`, `flag1`, etc., but instead the global variable is `flags`, the list.  The threads then modify `flags[flag1]` and `flag1` is `1`.

```
FLAG0, FLAG1, FLAG2, FLAG3 = range(4)
flags = [False] * 4
```

Or, to use the new `Enum` module ([enum34 is the backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)):

```
from enum import Enum

class Flags(Enum):
    flag0 = 0
    flag1 = 1
    flag2 = 2
    flag3 = 3
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._boolean = False
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self._boolean
    def set(self):
        "make the flag be True"
        self._boolean = True
    def clear(self):
        "make the flag be False"
        self._boolean = False

print Flags.flag0, bool(Flags.flag0)
Flags.flag0.set()
print Flags.flag0, bool(Flags.flag0)

the_flag_I_care_about = Flags.flag1
print the_flag_I_care_about, bool(the_flag_I_care_about)
the_flag_I_care_about.set()
print the_flag_I_care_about, bool(the_flag_I_care_about)
the_flag_I_care_about.clear()
print the_flag_I_care_about, bool(the_flag_I_care_about)
```

Oh, and just to be clear -- use better names than `flag0`, etc.  :)

Comment: This won't work. `flag0`, `flag1` get modified somewhere else, but `flags` (the list) won't change accordingly

Comment: But it's a list of references; the values in the list *are* the values of the actual flag variables. +1!

Comment: It's not a list of references! Python lists are pass-by-value, except for classes.

Comment: @Shane: My apologies for not explaining myself clearly -- `flags` is meant to be the replacement global variable.  I also added an example using the new `Enum` data type.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ethan's answer:

You can have a list of all the indexes, and then structure your `while` statement like this:

```
while flags[index]:
    # do stuff
```

You said that you edit the flag1 and flag2 objects (in other parts of the code, I assume), and that they don't change in the list. You can just reconstruct the list right before your `while` loop:

```
while [flag1, flag2, flag3, ...][index]:
    # do stuff
```

To have the "switch" statement you described, you'd need to have access to all your flag variables inside the `doSomething` function anyway, so it would be trivial to reconstruct the list.

Comment: looks like there are only `value_one` and `value_two` two choices?

Comment: Yes, ternaries only give you two choices. Do you want to have a while statement which can handle a bunch of different choices on one line?

Comment: Well, yes, that's the reason I want to find an elegant way of doing it.

Comment: NO, this won't work, see my edit. The only way to make it work is to structure the list directly into while sentence, and I still don't know why that guy ccame up with this deleted his answer.

Comment: Yes, it will work. I literally just recommended the exact same thing that you said would work, in a slightly different format. You __reconstruct__ the list inside the function each time. The only different is that I'm creating a variable for clarity, while the other person isn't storing the reconstructed list in a variable.

Comment: The thing is, when it executes to line `flags[index]`, you only get a boolean value which is not able to change afterwards, that means if it's `True`, it's `while True` forever, and in other threads no matter what you do to `flag1` it won't change `while True` sentence, which means it will run forever, what I'm trying to do is to stop it at some point. Don't know why you keep saying it will work, I've just tested it again, and it does NOT work, at least on my side.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there were __other threads__ editing the flags, I just thought that inbetween function calls they were being edited. I've edited my answer to have the correct answer.